Just showing a symbolic variable takes long time in Sympy
I am in trouble printing a symbolic variable in Sympy. I installed Sympy and mpmath by using the following commands:
conda install sympy
conda install mpmath

On JupyterLab, I'm trying to run the following, but the last line takes forever. I guess the problem is related to the rendering of mathematical expression, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I'm using Python 3.9.19 in Windows.
